# Is possible to change an app icon on 4.1 on my S3?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3

I have an app that I downloaded from the Play store and it's icon is very visually unappealing and I wanted to know if there is way to replace the default icon with one from an icon pack without a launcher.  Like, can I permanently associate a new icon with the app I want to change?  How can I do it? Or will the default icon always  show up in say, the Share menu but remain different on the homescreen?   Any tips?

OS: 4.1
S3

Answer (score 1):

- [Unicon](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=sg.ruqqq.IconThemer)
  is an icon theming tool which requires root, but it's more consistent throughout the      device.
- [Icon Changer](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.jy.iconchanger.ad) changes only the icon of the shortcut, but doesn't require root.
- Use [Apk Extractor](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=net.sylark.apkextractor) to get the installed apk from the device, transfer it to a PC, modify it and then reinstall it. Does not require root.

Comment: Icon changer didn't work at all. I wonder why...? Damn, no root or a PC.  :-(

Comment: Won't APK extractor require you to sign the new APK with a new key? This would mean you have to uninstall the app and lose its data to install your modified version.

Comment: @verve The Icon Changer app is only for shortcuts on the home screen: it won't change the icon in the app drawer or any other menu.

Answer (score 0):

If the icon changer that were suggested are not working, and you don't mind changing your launcher, there are some launchers that support icon changing (and also theme changing and more good stuff).

As example, you have:

- Go Launcher
- Nova Launcher

You can have a look at the play store, and also see what other launchers can offer you!